# Trying to write in text area using selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to comment in Instagram post by using selenium (java). Instagram Comment box in `textArea`, How can I add comment?
I did this...

```
WebElement cmdbox = driver.findElement(By.tagName("textarea"));
cmdbox.clear();
Thread.sleep(2000);
cmdbox.sendKeys("sample text");
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

I got this error

[image: error image]

Comment: Do you understand what selenium is actually meant for?

Comment: actually i write code for  search  #tags its works but now trying to auto comment, it simply clicks the comment box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ElementNotInteractableException** is Thrown to indicate that although an element is present on the DOM, it is not in a state that can be interacted with.

aka it is in the DOM but you cannot click on it yet. There are a few ways to solve this using `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()` is one way. A helper method could help before calling click.

```
 public static void waitForElementClickable(WebDriver webdriver, By by, long timeout) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, timeout);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
  }
```

Comment: yaa... now it click the element. but not add the text to the comment box.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, timeout); //15 can be ideal for timeout
```

//the code to clear area

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.tagName("textarea"))).clear();
```

//the code to sendKeys

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.tagName("textarea"))).sendKeys("sample text");
```

if this does not work, you can use **By.CssSelector("textarea.Ypffh")** as another alternative to the **By.tagName("textarea")**

Comment: ok let me try this...

Comment: ok if u have any problem let me know